# rolling over for

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "roll over for" mean? I've checked out "roll over", which has three definitions and none seems to be fit here:

> Randy Quaid tweeted on Nov 22:

> I just don’t see Americans **rolling over for** this election fraud. Do you?

> Twitter:  This claim about election fraud is disputed.

Comment: **roll over** [3. PHRASAL VERB](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roll-over) *If you say that someone rolls over, you mean that they **stop resisting** someone and do what the other person wants them to do.* Quaid thinks Americans will not passively accept the supposed election fraud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to submit.

*I just don’t see Americans submitting to  this election fraud. Do you?*

The origin of the phrase is from the way dogs indicate submission by rolling on their backs.

[image]

---

Note that, nowadays, there is some debate amongst animal psychologists about this gesture, however, traditionally, it has been understood to indicate submission.